# setting IPV6 in command line, Win PE

Tags: command-line, ipv6, winpe

Can i set the IPv6 ip address in command line? if possible please suggest me the command to use. I am using WinPE environment which is equalant to VISTA but with out GUI features installed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit of googling gave http://www.ipv6day.org/action.php?n=En.Configuration-WindowsVista

Use this:

```
netsh interface ipv6 add address "Local Area Connection" 2001:db8:290c:1291::1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "Buratinas". I was trying yesterday night for long time. But in a min you replied. Many thanks. I am setting up DHCPv6 server and DNS server. But facing lots of problems, like one or other thing will not work. Finally decided to give static ipv6 :) But dont have any GUI in winpe to assign IPV6. End up with assigning commandline. Your help is really nice. thanks a lot. ~itsmehara